# MongoDB Collection, sum all key values with terminal commands

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, command

Here an item of my table :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c20erefebddfbc9fdsff"),
"name" : "robe simple",
"price" : 4.9,
"unit" : "piece",
"price_type" : "flexible",
"updated_at" : ISODate("2019-12-30T09:06:35Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2018-12-24T14:23:25Z"),
"conciergerie_ids" : [
    "5c20ebefedcfbc9a103erfefeef921a9e2",
    "5c20ebdefsfcfbc9a1efsefe03b921a9e3",
    "5c20ebdsefefcfbc9a1sefef03b921a9e4",
],
}
```

I need to sum all price of a specific conciergerie, created_at 2019 only.

I tried this :

```
> db.prestations.find({'conciergerie_ids': '5c20ebseffhhb3b921adfdf9ef'}).count({ $sum: 'price' })
```

But i get just the total  of all items corresponding to my conciergerie.

I tried this too :

```
> db.prestations.find({'conciergerie_ids': '5c20ebdcfbefefc9a103b921afefef9ef'}).aggregate([ { $group: total: {{ $sum: "$price" }} } ])
```

How can i get the sum of all price of a specific conciergerie and only created at 2019 ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                { 'conciergerie_ids': '5c20ebdcfbc9a103b921a9ef'},
                { created_at: { $gte: ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") } }
            ]           
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            total: { $sum: "$price" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KuO2dmNwGU_)